# Deployment in bamboo for different environments

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, bamboo, continuous-delivery

I have a few concerns with my deployment plan on bamboo. It's a java project with maven for build.

So, we have a project where there are multiple modules and the basic structure used is the one defined by maven. The path to resources is also default `src/main/resources`

**The deployment plan has these 3 tasks :**

> i>Artifact download
>
> ii>Script
>
> iii>Maven 3.X
>
> iv>Deployment Plugin

**Now there are couple of things which are bothering me with respect to the deployment plan :**

1. We have multiple environments and hence there is an inline script
   task (ii) in the deployment plan opens the .properties file from the
   artifact (in this case a jar) unzips the jar rewrites the values and
   zips it up. Shouldn't we handle this in a better way? Tried having
   the different .properties file for different environment and use the
   maven profiling but the problem with this approach is one of the
   modules has 20 .property files and across 3 environments which
   implies there are 60 files! That's cumbersome to manage.
2. We use the command in goal for the step (iii) ' -U -e -X clean
   install' and then set the environment variables too.  *Shouldn't we
   use 'deploy' instead of `-U -e -X clean install` and can the
   environment variables such as `SR_INSTANCE`,`SR_MEMORY` etc. be managed
   else where?*